# \index command doesn't work in a simple newcommand

Tags: indexing

When I write the following code, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\p}{\raisebox{2pt}{$\mathfrak{p}$}}

\begin{document}

$\p(E)$\index{$\p(E)$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

But what I need is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\p}{\raisebox{2pt}{$\mathfrak{p}$}}

\newcommand{\idxx}[1]{$#1$\index{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\idxx{\p(E)}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

But it fails. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\p}{\raisebox{2pt}{$\mathfrak{p}$}}`

Comment: for situations like this, i'd recommend using a sort field for the index; i'm sure that "`\raisebox`" will *not* sort into any useful order by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Either you `\protect` the `\p` command inside `\index`, or better yet, use `\DeclareRobustCommand` in the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\p}{\raisebox{2pt}{$\mathfrak{p}$}}

\newcommand{\idxx}[1]{$#1$\index{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\idxx{\p(E)}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand\p{\protect\raisebox{2pt}{$\mathfrak{p}$}}
```

However, in general it is not a good idea to define macros with a name of a single character. There are some internal ones predefined.